In unit tests, how to mock values in test classes before the constructor of injected service class works
I am writing unit tests for a service class, let's call it MyService, which is in the following format:
public class MyService {

    private final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

    public MyService(MyRepository myRepository) {
        headers.setBasicAuth(myRepository.getValue("login"), myRepository.getValue("password"));
  }
   
   // OTHER PARTS OF THE CODE
}

In the constructor of MyService class, I am setting values to headers field. When writing unit tests, I am facing the problem which will be described below:
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyService.class)
class MyServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @BeforeEach
    void init() {
        mockValue("login", "login_value");
        mockValue("password", "password_value");
    }

   // OTHER PARTS OF THE CODE
}

I have a method mockValue which mocks the values appropriately. the problem is:
The constructor of MyService works before the init() method of MyServiceTest. As a result, myRepository.getValue("login") is returning null and headers.setBasicAuth() method is throwing exception: "Username must not be null".
How to handle it? How to mock values before constructor of MyService works?
I tried to create another class, inside which I can mock values and inject it to my test class. It didn't work as I expected.

If autowiring isn't working for you, why not new up the class yourself - new MyService(mockRepo)?

@jonrsharpe is right; Better to use constructor based injection;

I am not allowed to change the MyService class

use @TestConfiguration
Unless your goal is to also test the repository, I guess it is to insert basic auth into the service, in order to use it with something like WireMock.
If you are not a fan of ReflectionTestUtils this is another solution.
@SpringBootTest
class MyServiceTest {
    @TestConfiguration
    static class MyServiceTestConfig {
        @Bean
        public MyService myService() {
            final MyRepository myRepository = Mockito.mock(MyRepository.class);
            Mockito.when(myRepository.getValue("login")).thenReturn("mocked_login_value");
            Mockito.when(myRepository.getValue("password")).thenReturn("mocked_password_value");
            return new MyService(myRepository);
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @Test
    void invokeService() {
        //bW9ja2VkX2xvZ2luX3ZhbHVlOm1vY2tlZF9wYXNzd29yZF92YWx1ZQ==" is equal to mocked_login_value:mocked_password_value
        Assertions.assertEquals("Basic bW9ja2VkX2xvZ2luX3ZhbHVlOm1vY2tlZF9wYXNzd29yZF92YWx1ZQ==", myService.getHeader("authorization"));
    }
}


You could use ReflectionTestUtils
@Service
public class MyService {
    private final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

    public MyService(MyRepository myRepository) {
        headers.setBasicAuth(myRepository.getValue("login"), myRepository.getValue("password"));
    }

    public String getHeader(String key){
        return headers.getFirst(key);
    }

}


@SpringBootTest
class MyServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @BeforeEach
    void init() {
        mockValue("mocked_login_value", "mocked_password_value");
    }

    private void mockValue(String login_value, String password_value) {
        final HttpHeaders value = new HttpHeaders();
        value.setBasicAuth(login_value, password_value);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(myService, "headers", value);
    }

    @Test
    void invokeService() {
        //bW9ja2VkX2xvZ2luX3ZhbHVlOm1vY2tlZF9wYXNzd29yZF92YWx1ZQ==" is equal to mocked_login_value:mocked_password_value
        Assertions.assertEquals("Basic bW9ja2VkX2xvZ2luX3ZhbHVlOm1vY2tlZF9wYXNzd29yZF92YWx1ZQ==", myService.getHeader("authorization"));
    }
}


I tested it locally and it works. Not elegant, but as you can not change MyService, it is probably the easiest to do.
